# Are charges made on application updates?

Tags: software-center, application-development, paid-applications

I'm planning to develop an open source application and am also considering to set a non-zero price for it.

If an user purchases the app, will he be charged again when updates are released?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From my experience with the Software Center and the Humble Indie Bundle apps, **no**, they will not be charged again.  I've installed updates to Bastion without any re-payment, though I redeemed the Bundle apps via the gift codes, so it might be different for store-bought apps.

### Technical

When you purchase an app, it adds a private repository (a.k.a. PPA, or personal package archive) to the folder `/etc/apt/sources.list.d`, e.g. `private-ppa.launchpad.net_commercial-ppa-uploaders_bastion_ubuntu.list`.  The URL inside the file does not change when the app is updated, so I assume you will never have to re-purchase as long as the app is not republished under a new name.

Comment: Thank you, and the additional details are very helpful, too.

Comment: @Shane can change the assumption to fact. You will not be charged for updates.

Answer (score 4):

The answer is no, they will not be charged again if updates to the app are released.